# Herokuのcedar-14スタックは2019年４月から使えないのでしょうか？

Tags: heroku

現在、Herokuのcedar-14スタック上でアプリケーションを稼働させています。

下記ページによるとcedar-14はSupported through「April 2019」となっています。
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack

2019/4/1からアプリケーションは使えなくなるのでしょうか？

Comment: 英語に疎いのでこの様な質問に至りました。皆様の回答を頂き、とりあえずですがgemを一つだけ更新して使えるheroku-16スタックにアップグレードして延命しました。近くrailsのバージョンも上げてheroku-18スタックにアップグレードします。

Answer (score 1):

この業界において、サポート期限切れというのは一般的に
- 使用不可能になるという意味ではない
- 使い続けてもいいけど、あなたの責任で使ってね
- バグや脆弱性やその他不都合があっても、提供者は手入れをしないよ
という意味です（提供者側の責任放棄ってこと）。

現に Win XP や Win Vista はサポートが切れた今でも「使用できなく」なっていません（ Heroku は違うかもしれませんが）。「実用できる」かどうかはまた別問題です。例えば証明書の更新や SSL/TLS のサポート更新がなされないので Win XP で今時の https サイトは正しく見ることができませんし、安全性は０です。

既に Ceder-14 は deprecated なので、今のうちに Heroku-18 でのテストをしてバージョンアップすることを強く推奨します。

Answer (score 1):

結論として、**2019年4月からアプリケーションは使えなくなる**と思われます。

[Cedar-14 is now deprecated](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1413)というページにおいて以下のように記述されています。

> After April 2019 builds for apps running on Cedar-14 will no longer work.

2019年4月以降、Cedar-14で動作しているアプリのbuildは動作しなくなるとされています。（すみませんが、Herokuを使っていないのでこのbuildが正確に何を意味するのか分かっていません。）

また、[Stack Update Policy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack-update-policy)のページにおいて以下のように記述されています。

> Old stacks are retired when they are no longer receiving support from Canonical (5 years after Canonical introduces that LTS release). Heroku will notify users with apps on old stacks before they are retired. Notifications are in the form of Changelog entries and direct emails to owners and collaborators on apps running on stacks that are about to be retired.

サポートが切れたスタックはretireするとあります。

また、少し古いドキュメントですが、[Cedar-14 now Generally Available](https://blog.heroku.com/cedar_14_now_generally_available)には以下の記載があります（強調は回答者）。

> Stacks cannot live forever – packages and distro versions are deprecated or stop receiving security updates. With Cedar-14 GA, we’re also announcing the deprecation of the classic Cedar runtime stack: A year from now, on November 4th, 2015, the classic Cedar stack will be retired and **any apps that have not been migrated to Cedar-14 will stop running**. You must migrate all apps to Cedar-14 before this date to prevent disruption in availability. In the coming year, we will keep the old Cedar stack image patched and updated.

2015年11月にサポートが切れたclassic Cedar stackの場合は、その時点でアプリの動作も停止するということが明言されていました。

以上のことから、2019年4月になった時点でアプリケーションが使えなくなると考えられます。

Comment: 現在のアプリケーション(rails)の状態ではheroku-18環境への移行は影響が大きいので、heroku-16環境で延命しました。